# Perl JOIN in a different way?

Tags: arrays, perl, join

I am working on a perl module and looking for an output (string) of the form : `a:value1 OR a:value2 OR a:value3 OR ...`

The values `value1, value2, value3...` are in an array (say, @values).

I know we could use `join( ' OR ', @values )` to create a concatenated string of the form: `value1 OR value2 OR value3 OR ...`

But as you see above, I need an additional `a:` to be prepended to each value.

What would be a neat way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically use [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) for these kinds of things:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw(value1 value2 value3);
print join(" OR ", map "a:$_", @array),"\n";
```

Output:

```
a:value1 OR a:value2 OR a:value3
```

`map` is a simple looping construct, which is useful when you want to do apply some simple logic to every element of a list without making too much clutter of your code.

Comment: While `map` may be implemented as a loop internally, its purpose is to provide a *mapping* or *function* that maps one list into another by transforming all the elements of the list according to the same rule. It isn't useful to think of it as a *looping construct*.

Comment: @Borodin: Looping construct was meant more as a concise way of describing what `map` does than a formal definition. If you can suggest another term, I'd be happy to update the answer.

Comment: Is is useful to regard it as looping if you carry over state from one iteration to the next, especially if the end result depends on the order of execution.

Comment: You say "It isn't useful to think of it as a looping construct." after explaining it is ("transforming all the elements"). (Should be "each", not "all", though. You know, like "for each", but it's "map each" here.)